# Error while trying to authenticate in joomla template

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I have bought a joomla template for personal use. I am running it locally with xampp. When trying to login in the administrator/index.php, I receive the following error:

```
Class 'Joomla\Plugin\Authentication\Joomla\Extension\Cookie' not found
```

I've seen some solution to disable this extension in the phpMyAdmin, did that and then it turned into

```
Class 'Joomla\Plugin\Authentication\Joomla\Extension\Joomla' not found
```

After doing the same for this one, I receive

```
JAuthentication: :__construct: Could not load authentication libraries.
```

I have found just a few examples of a similar occurrence(with the first error, with cookie extension), but it was happening when updating to joomla 4.3.0 ( I was not updating, I don't have access to control panel as I'm not able to login as admin)

I've tried some options mentioned there ( eg deleting administrator/cache/autoload_psr4.php) but did not work.
(mention: in administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml, the version is 4.2.8)

Please input any thought you have on what is happening and what could be done?